# Basic Fusion Tables API: How do you do an update query correctly?

Tags: api, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

i am referring to an Fusion Tables API Example „Update Query“ https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/change_query
It's is about a drop-down menu which alters the content of the layer upon the map.

I tried to rebuild the whole example on my own site, but i didn't work out yet. I narrowed down possible mistakes and pitfalls to the part where the layer (with data from my google fusion table) gets initialized. 
It looks like that in the google example:

```
    var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
      query: {
        select: locationColumn,
        from: tableId
      },
      map: map
    });
```

Here is the code which worked out for me in every of my own examples with fusion tables, except for the one shown above.

```
var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(tableid)
layer.setMap(map);
```

Here is the link for the live code: http://krealeo12.appspot.com/

As i am new to this whole API and JavaScript thing, i can not distinguish why the first example doesn't work and the second does?! What is the difference, and more important, what does it mean?

I am very thankful for every hint and advice! 
J.

Comment: I don't totally understand what you are trying to do. Do you wish to add a dropdown to your live code? Or just load your Fusion Table data using the first, larger chunk of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue also confused me when I started using Fusion Tables.  You will find many examples where  deprecated methods are used:

```
var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(tableid)
layer.setMap(map);
layers.setQuery("select * from " + tableid + " where ridership > 5000");
```

The first example you quote is the proper way to do it. What was most confusing is that you cannot combine the two approaches.  E.g.  last time I checked, the following will not work.  The initial map will display fine but the query will not work.

```
var layer = FusionTablesLayer(tableid);
var layer.setOptions{
    query: {
     select: 'address',
     from: '198945',
     where: 'ridership > 5000'
  }
});
```

The proper way is described in the [docs](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/layers.html#FusionTables)

Comment: Of course I'm assuming it's not just your typo: from tableId vs. tableid.

Comment: Thanks for your good advice. I am trying to work with the way described in the doc. Nevertheless i still got a problem with the change query issue. I basically tried to combine the Google Fusion Tables Layer samples "Legend" and "Update Query". http://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/legend http://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/change_query Although i checked the code for mistakes and typos, i cannot find the why the query is not working, when I click and select an item from the drop down menu. Any idea? Thanks in advance Link: http://sportstleo12.appspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

Really another question, so I'm adding a new answer.  You've got an error in your updateMap() function.

```
 function updateMap(layer, tableid, locationColumn) {
        var sportart = document.getElementById('search-string').value;
        if (sportart) {
          layer.setOptions({
            query: {
              select: locationColumn,
              from: tableid,
              where: "sportart = '" + search-string + "'" // ERROR
            }
          });
        } else {
          layer.setOptions({
            query: {
              select: locationColumn,
              from: tableid
            }
          });
        }
      }
```

The select list search value is called "sportart" not "search-string".

Answer (score 0):

Google does not provide error messages from queries, so you may need to use trial and error and a search for examples to get results.  This worked for me.  Note the quotes around the whole string (as you'd expect), plus the quotes around the date.

```
     layer.setOptions({
       query:{
            select: "col1",
            from: "1Ayaf5aKAanSv6HAtsTLtcAhrnpF94XyuNZ9u_Sk",
            where: "Date<'01/01/2011'"
         },
         styles:[{
                 markerOptions:{
                        iconName:'measle_gray'
                }
            }]
      });
```

A useful but hard-to-find page describes acceptable date formats, among other things: 
https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/sql-reference
I do not know why many colors of small dot are called "measle_" rather than "small_"

Answer (score 0):

You can use this,

```
 var fusionOptions = {

          query: {
            select: "Geometry",
            from: "tableId",
            where: ""
          },

        styles: [{

          where: 'Available_Impressions <  605173',
          polygonOptions: {
            fillColor: '#88bad8',
            fillOpacity: 0.8
          }
        }, {
          where: 'Available_Impressions > 605173',
          polygonOptions: {
            fillColor: '#5792c3',
            fillOpacity: 0.8
          }
        }, {
          where: 'Available_Impressions > 1210347',
          polygonOptions: {
            fillColor: '#4572ab',
            fillOpacity: 0.8
          }
        }]          

    }
```